# Store output for multiple ForEach into array and append results powershell

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

```
$results = @()
foreach($JobObject1 in $JobObjects1){
$Jobs1 = $JobObject1.getAbatObject();
foreach($Job1 in $Jobs1){
write-host("Name :" + $Job1.Name)
write-host("Path :" + $Job1.Path)
}
foreach($JobObject2 in $JobObjects2){
$Jobs2 = $JobObject2.getAbatObject();
foreach($Job2 in $Jobs2){
write-host("Name :" + $Job2.Name)
write-host("Path :" + $Job2.Path)
}
    $details = @{
            TradeSupport_Schedule_Name = $Job1.Name
            TradeSupport_Schedule_Path = $Job1.FullPath
            Operations_Schedule_Name = $Job2.Name
            Operations_Schedule_Path = $Job2.FullPath

    }
    $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details

write-host("************************************************************")
}
}
$results | select-object -property TradeSupport_Schedule_Name,TradeSupport_Schedule_Path,Operations_Schedule_Name,Operations_Schedule_Path | export-csv -Path \\ch0-craab-01\c$\Support\AB_Reports\Objects_Report.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I'm trying to figure out how to take the output of each individual foreach statement and store the results into an array so I may then combine them in the csv. As the script stands, it iterates the first statement against the second. I want each result printed side by side.

Comment: Do the two objects have a property in common?

Comment: There are 4 foreach statements in your code. I suggest that you format your code so that the nested structures are more visible, maybe at some comments on what the objects represent and be more specific which data you want to combine. Maybe an example output would be also useful. Because I can recognize in your code the concept of building up an array, and therefore you understand the principal so I don't understand what you are missing.